# How can I get HTML content after logging in Instagram with requests library

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

**This question was edited, see update below**

I'm trying to get the title(HTML tag content) of certain url for when it responds 404. I want to get the content only when returns 404 because I'm testing if an instagram username is avaiable using urls with that username like this:

```
https://instagram.com/jsd23sdoleo
```

Which returns a 404 html page with the title **Page Not Found**.

Now there's urls like this:

```
https://www.instagram.com/leop
```

[Content Unavaiable screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OlHX.png)
[Page not found screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eNsg.png)

Where it returns the title **Content Unavaiable** in the browser . It turns out that when it returns "Content Unavaiable" the usename is not taken but also not avaiable. The only case that is not taken and avaiable is when it returns "Page not Found".

But my python code it is only bringing **Page Not Found** as the title even for urls that in the browser shows **Content Unavaiable**.

Is there a reason for not getting the right HTML content for those urls?

**UPDATE: My python code brings only "Page Not Found" because when I test in my browser I'm logged in, so the behavior is different. 
Is there a way of getting the HTML page after the loggin with the requests library?**

Here's my code so you can test it:

```py
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

chars_clean = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','x','z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
chars = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','x','z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','_','.']
base_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/'
leo = 'leo'
urls = []
valid_urls = []
user = []

for char_clean in chars_clean:
  for char in chars:
    urls.append(base_url + char_clean + char + leo)



for url in urls:
  try:
    #fetch html
    source = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    #parse with BeautifulSoup
    BS = BeautifulSoup(source, "html5lib")
    #search for title element, print element.text
    title = BS.title.string
  except urllib.error.URLError as err:
    if err.code == 404:

      response = requests.get(url)
      soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html5lib")
      title = soup.title.string
      print("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
      print(url)
      #x = url.split('m/')
      print(title) # Prints
      print('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
      continue
    else:
      valid_urls.append(url)
```

Comment: for the record, I'm seeing the same behavior in both the browser and using `requests`. I'm wondering if they dynamically set the title in browser, but couldn't find where they would be doing that in the page source

Comment: Thanks wpercy for your debug perspective. I checked if it was my browser and I tested these urls with incognito mode and it shows now "Page Not Found" for both urls. I was logged in at my normal browser session, thats why the behavior is different there. I'll update the question about getting html page after login with requests library.

Comment: with the request library you cannot see pages as logged in, but you can try cookies see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48849635/8980073. Otherwise I recommend selenium for python.

Comment: @Lukas that's exactly what's happening, nice find

Comment: Hey Lukas, I studied the code from this stack, implemented here and it is working perfectly, now I can login with requests and also fetch HTML while logged in. Nice find indeed. Thanks wpercy and Lukas!!