# How to get instagram sessionid using python + requests

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I want to get `sessionid` from Instagram cookies using `requests` module.

I tried code which described in this question [Instagram Authentification with python and requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48835661/instagram-authentification-with-python-and-requests)
but it doesn't work.
is there any way how to get it? before or after login.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this script to login to Instagram:

```
import re
import requests

from datetime import datetime

link = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/'
login_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/'

time = int(datetime.now().timestamp())

payload = {
    'username': '<USERNAME HERE>',
    'enc_password': f'#PWD_INSTAGRAM_BROWSER:0:{time}:<PASSWORD HERE>',
    'queryParams': {},
    'optIntoOneTap': 'false'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(link)
    csrf = re.findall(r"csrf_token\":\"(.*?)\"",r.text)[0]
    r = s.post(login_url,data=payload,headers={
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "Referer": "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/",
        "x-csrftoken":csrf
    })
    print(r.status_code)
    print(r.url)
    print(r.text)

    print(s.cookies)
```

Prints (the `sessionid` is inside the cookies):

```
200
https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/
{"user": true, "userId": "XXX", "authenticated": true, "oneTapPrompt": true, "reactivated": true, "status": "ok"}
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie csrftoken=XXX for .instagram.com/>, <Cookie ds_user_id=XXX for .instagram.com/>, <Cookie mid=XXX for .instagram.com/>, <Cookie rur=ATN for .instagram.com/>, <Cookie sessionid=<SESSION ID> for .instagram.com/>]>
```

Comment: Should `"x-csrftoken":csrf` be `"x-csrftoken": csrf`? My linter seems to think so.